# TCA (flexform) multi select

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I work on an extension and for a plugin I want to select specific records. For that I created a flexform with a TCA select configuration:

```
<T3DataStructure>
  <meta>
    <langDisable>1</langDisable> 

  </meta>
  <sheets>
    <sDEF>
      <ROOT>
        <TCEforms>
          <sheetTitle>TEST</sheetTitle>
        </TCEforms>
        <type>array</type>
        <el>


          <settings.selection>
            <TCEforms>
              <exclude>1</exclude>
              <label>Selection</label>
              <config>
                <type>select</type>      
                <foreign_table>tx_mycollection_domain_model_mycollection</foreign_table>
                <renderType>selectCheckBox</renderType>
                <size>5</size>
                <minItems>3</minItems>
                <maxItems>999</maxItems>
                <foreign_table_where>AND tx_mycollection_domain_model_mycollection.sys_language_uid=###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###</foreign_table_where>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.selection>

        </el>
      </ROOT>
    </sDEF>
  </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

It looks fine, in the backend I have checkboxes to select the records. But when I save the plugin only the first checkbox is checked/saved.

Is there something wrong in the configuration or what could be the reason that I can not save multible values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<minItems>3</minItems>
<maxItems>999</maxItems>
```

From the documentation here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#properties

These needs to be specified as all lower case, so changing them to:

```
<minitems>3</minitems>
<maxitems>999</maxitems>
```

Should resolve your issue. It is saving only 1 right now, since maxitems by default is set to 1.